# Translate months on the WordPress Plugin Age Verify

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, translation

I'm not very good with php and I've got a little problem with the plugin Age Verify. It offers a french translation but the month aren't translated. I checked the code and I found 2 functions.php :
/plugins/age-verify/functions.php
/plugins/age-verify/includes/functions.php

In both of them there is this :

```
$form .= '<p><select name="av_verify_m" id="av_verify_m">';
foreach ( range( 1, 12 ) as $month ) :
$month_name = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1 ) );
$form .= '<option value="' . $month . '">' . $month_name . '</option>';
endforeach;
```

I tried to insert `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');` before the `$month_name` line but it didn't work.

Also, I specify that the plugin has a language folder with an fr_FR.pot but the months aren't translated in that file.

If someone can help & why not explain to me how to translate the months, it would be very nice !

And sorry for my bad english ...

Comment: Try to add months and its translation in .pot file and then check.

Comment: Is there someone else to help me ?

Comment: Ok so I found the solution :

Replace 
`$form .= '<p><select name="av_verify_m" id="av_verify_m">';
foreach ( range( 1, 12 ) as $month ) :
$month_name = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1 ) );
$form .= '<option value="' . $month . '">' . $month_name . '</option>';
endforeach;`      by    `foreach ( range( 1, 12 ) as $month ) :
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
$month_name = ucfirst( utf8_encode( strftime( '%B', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1 ) ) ) );
$form .= '<option value="' . $month . '">' . $month_name . '</option>';
endforeach;`   in the two functions.php files